# Prevent hsl turning into hex color with Sass

Tags: sass

Why HSL colors turns into hexadecimal format when using Sass?

```
.bgcolor{
  background-color: hsl(205,74%,66%);
  /* background-color: #68b3e8; */
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out this Sass [issue](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/469) and I realized two ways of preventing this conversion to happen:

1. Overwriting hsl Sass native function

   ```
   @function hsl($h, $s, $l) {
     @return unquote('hsl(#{$h}, #{$s}, #{$l})');
   }

   .bgcolor{
     background-color: hsl(205,74%,66%);
   }
   ```
2. String it with `#{}` interpolation

   ```
   .bgcolor{
     background-color: #{'hsl(205,74%,66%)'};
   }
   ```